# Catalina: Notarizing an electron app - do we need a new app ID and register it in Apple?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

so far I've been distributing a dmg version of my app on my GitHub page for Mac users. It wasn't signed/notarized. I am now going through the process of using `electron-osx-sign` et al to get it notarized. I do not plan to distribute it via the Mac App store. I still plan to host the dmg on my GitHub page. I keep getting errors about not using the right developer certificate.

Questions:

1. Do I need to create a NEW appID in apple for my electron app? I already have an app-id for the iOS version that is distributed through the iOS app store. Let's say that is `com.me.myapp` and I was using the developer certificate for that.
2. Is there a guide on exactly which certificates/profiles I need to download and point my electron-osx-sign tool to? all tutorials I've read focus on the entitlements and notarization hooks but don't really talk about the profile/certificate part in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I need a "Mac Developer ID". No need to create a new app id.